# How can I use kusto to show which permissions are being used by which users on the data plane

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-diagnostics, azure-rbac

We are trying to analyze which Azure permissions are being used by which users, so that we can trim our custom roles back to only include permissions that are being used.

We have configured all of our Azure resources to send all logs and metrics to a Log Analytics Workspace.

As I understand it, any management plane actions are pushed into the AzureActivity table while any actions on the data plane are pushed into the AzureDiagnostics table.

From the AzureActivity table (in OperationNameValue field) we can see when users are performing actions like

MICROSOFT.INSIGHTS/DIAGNOSTICSETTINGS/WRITE

Which is exactly what we need, we can use this to ensure the custom RBAC role includes that permission.

However in the AzureDiagnostics table we can only pull the OperationName field which returns values such as...

ListPrivateEndpointConnections
VaultGet
SecretSet
SecretGet

How can we map these across to the permissions associated with the DataActions?

For example "SecretGet" requires "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets/getSecret/action"

Comment: To better assist you, could you please provide more details about what you've already tried to solve the issue? Any code snippets, error messages, or specific steps you've taken so far would be helpful. This information will help the community better understand your problem and provide more accurate solutions.